# How to Convert Binary String into Array Of Integer Bit using Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, string, excel, binary, vba

I'm having hardstop with this problem to solve in my Excel macro coding. My input data is a binary string '1110'. Need to extract the binary string and return each bit of binary in sequence into array (as integer bit). Pls help me...really appreciate help for coaching.

For each bit = 1, the array value for that bit = Power of 2. At the end, add up all the value. Example:

Input = 1110 (binary string) store into Array (i). i = 3 (total bit from input =4)

```
Array (0) = 1^2 to the pwr of 0 = 1
Array (1) = 1^2 to the pwr of 1 = 2
Array (2) = 1^2 to the pwr of 2 = 4
Array (3) = 1^2 to the pwr of 3 = 8
```

The final output to be returned is summation of all the array list.In this case, it'll be 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head without testing this will get you close.

```
Dim bin as String

bin="1101"

Dim bits(Len(bin)) as Integer

Dim bitIndex as Integer

Dim sum as Integer
sum = 0
For bitIndex = 0 to Len(bin)-1
  bits(bitIndex) = CInt(Mid(bin,bitIndex+1, 1)) * (2 ^ bitIndex)
  Debug.Print bits(bitIndex)
  sum = sum + bits(bitIndex) 
Next

Debug.Print sum
```

Comment: thanks Rene. I've been thinking too much. That's a simple workable soultion. Thank u very much...ur help is so appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can get the final answer using the built-in Excel function BIN2DEC (from the analysis Toolpak)

Comment: i'm afraid BIN2DEC will not work here as i'm not looking for a direct binary to decimal translation. Once binary obtained from the binary string, it has to be manipulated with power of 2 & sum all the values up.  Thanks Charles for the advise, though :)